# play framework evolution issue on deleting or updating model name

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am having a big issue understanding evolutions in play framework ,

When i make a model named "questions" then  follow evolution appears

```
# --- !Ups

create table questions (
Id                        varchar(255) not null,
question                  varchar(255),
constraint pk_questions primary key (Id))
;

# --- !Downs

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

drop table questions;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

now when i delete this model and make one named Questions then also the evolution stays same,

```
# --- !Ups

create table questions (
Id                        varchar(255) not null,
question                  varchar(255),
constraint pk_questions primary key (Id))
;

# --- !Downs

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

drop table questions;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

when i update questions next time then it shows something like this(delete question variable)

```
create table questions (
Id                        varchar(255) not null,
question                  varchar(255),
constraint pk_questions primary key (Id))
;

create table questions (
Id                        varchar(255) not null,

constraint pk_questions primary key (Id))
;
# --- !Downs

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

drop table questions;

drop table questions;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**why won't it update the table name also? there is no relevant documentation i could find so this is my last hope :(.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have two class : questions and Questions ? If this is the case it is considered bad practices and you should rename one in another format. Moroever all of the class should begin by an upper case character. This should solve your problem.
If you are not satisfied with the name of the table generated by ebean, use this annotation on your class :

```
@Table(name="whatever_name_i_want")  
class MyClass
{
}
```

I recommand you to use only lower case table name (some data base are not case sensitive).

The fact that the table name is the same wether the first letter is upper case or lower case is because ebean translate camel case class name into snake case table name.
In snake case all the letters are lower case.

Comment: actually at first i made class questions and when i tried to replace it with new Questions model , it dod not update "create questions" to "create Questions" in the evolution file 1.sql :( , is there some configuration for such cases?

Comment: This is absolutely normal : when creating table names, ebean take the name of the class and modify it to lower case. If this is a problem you can @Table(name="my_name") (I edited my answer to add more details).

Comment: i don't think ebean converts class name to lowercase, can you tell me the source which supports what you said there?i tried the table name approach but this error doesn't disappear .

Comment: http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/config/UnderscoreNamingConvention.html : Converts between Camel Case and Underscore based names for both table and column names (and is the default naming convention in Ebean).